# i am trying to get the the variance of derivative of order 2. i only have the data of an EEG signal sampled at 128 Hz. is the below code correct

Tags: classification, feature-extraction, variance, interpolation, derivation

## I basically want to implement equation 7 present in the added image

```
interpolation=CubicSpline(x,y)

x_interp = np.linspace(0, 1, 129)

y_interp = interpolation(x_interp,2)

var=np.var(y_interp)

df=((np.sqrt(2*22/7*2.7*var))/(1+np.sqrt(2*22/7*2.7*var)))
```

[image]